# Get Inner Json String Data from Main Json String using Gson

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I am using `Gson` to parse data from Json String. Everything is working fine.
But now, Main `Json String` contains Inner Json String and I want that Inner `Json String`'s data. How to get it ?
**Check my `Json String`:**

```
[{"Question":"Are you inclined to:","QId":"2","Options":[{"Option":"Argue or debate issues","OptionId":"4"},{"Option":"Avoid arguments","OptionId":"5"},{"Option":"Swutch topics","OptionId":"6"}]}]
```

**Here, I want value of "Options".


My Sample code is as below :**

```
    PrimaryTest[] testlist = gson.fromJson(result, PrimaryTest[].class); // result is Json String.
    List<PrimaryTest> lstTest = Arrays.asList(testlist);
    PrimaryTest objTest = lstTest.get(0);
    String Question = objTest.getQuestion();
```

Here, I am getting Question value perfectly but don't know how to get Options value. If I am using same method then It is giving error : `Invalid Json Data`.
**PrimaryTest.java Code :**

```
public class PrimaryTest {

    private String Question;

    public PrimaryTest(String Question) {
        this.Question = Question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String Question) {
        this.Question = Question;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.Question;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for your PriamryTest class (the one which instances of it should be de-serialized from the json string)

Comment: "Options" is inside an object which is inside an array.  Access the array element (List) to get the object (Map), then extract "Options", which will be an object (Map).  You can't extract it as a String.  If you want a String run the object/Map through a JSON encoder.  (It's silly to bother with POJOs for this -- they will just get in the way.)

Comment: @HotLicks, can you give me any example ?

Comment: You mean write your code for you?  I clearly described it above.  `List list = parse(jsonString);  Map map1 = list[0];  Map map2 = map1.get("Options");  String innerJson = serialize(map2);`  Just substitute the methods and types used by your parser of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your class which include parameter which your JSON string contain so that you can directly parse your string into class object.
Your `PrimaryTest` class should contain following members :

```
public class PrimaryTest {  
    private String Question;  
    private int QId;  
    private List<Option> Options;  

    //Getter and Setter methods here
}
```

And your `Option` class contain members as shown below :

```
public class Option{  
   private String Option;  
   private int OptionId;  

   // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Now parse your JSON string in as `PrimaryTest` class and get your `Options` list from getter method of class.

Below is the test code :

```
PrimaryTest[] response = gson.fromJson(json, PrimaryTest[].class);
List<PrimaryTest> lstTest = Arrays.asList(response);
PrimaryTest objTest = lstTest.get(0);

List<Option> options = objTest.getOptions();
for(Option option : options){
    System.out.println(option.getOption());
}
```

Comment: yes, it is perfect solution. I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint an how the objects could be.

```
OptionClass{
String Option 
int/long OptionId
}

QuestionClass{
String Question
int/long QId
Collection<OptionClass> Options
}
```

Note: This is not a java class. Design your class based on the hints.